# Как сделать кнопку "назад в меню" в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Мне нужна помощь,я пишу бота хочу сделать кнопку "назад в меню" как её сделать?

Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start","help"])
def welcome(message):
    hello = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Приветсвую вас меня зовут Бот!")
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    mrk = types.KeyboardButton("Каталог")
    mrk1 = types.KeyboardButton("Корзина")
    markup.add(mrk,mrk1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите в меню,что вам интересно", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_text(message):
    if message.text == "Каталог":
        markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        mar = types.KeyboardButton("Одежда")
        mar2 = types.KeyboardButton("Назад в меню")
        markup1.add(mar,mar2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите,что вам нужно,если хотите вернуться в меню просто нажмите кнопку 'Назад в меню' ",reply_markup=markup1)
    elif message.text == "Назад в меню":
        pass
 
 
 
 
 
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код в виде текста, а не в виде картинки.

Comment: Добавил код в виде текста

Answer (score 1):

Для начала Вам нужно посмотреть обучающие видео (можно на YouTube)
Но... У Вас неправильное построение
Есть такая штука как `callback_data`, её мы пишем в `KeyboardButton`:

```
mrk = types.KeyboardButton("Каталог", callback_data='katalog')
mrk1 = types.KeyboardButton("Корзина", callback_data='cart')
```

После этого создаём новый хендлер -

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
```

И новую функцию в нём

```
def answer(call):
```

Прошу заметить что тут уже не `message`, а `call`
И далее пишем что делать если была нажата кнопка -

```
if call.data == 'katalog':
    markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    mar = types.KeyboardButton("Одежда", callback_data=odezda)
    mar2 = types.KeyboardButton("Назад в меню", callback_data=back)
    markup1.add(mar,mar2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите,что вам нужно,если хотите вернуться в меню просто нажмите кнопку 'Назад в меню' ",reply_markup=markup1)
elif call.data == 'cart':
    # Что то
elif call.data == 'back':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню",reply_markup=None)
```

Всё вместе -

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start","help"])
def welcome(message):
    hello = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Приветсвую вас меня зовут Бот!")
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    mrk = types.KeyboardButton("Каталог", callback_data='katalog')
    mrk1 = types.KeyboardButton("Корзина", callback_data='cart')
    markup.add(mrk,mrk1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите в меню,что вам интересно", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call): 
    if call.data == 'katalog':
    markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    mar = types.KeyboardButton("Одежда", callback_data=odezda)
    mar2 = types.KeyboardButton("Назад в меню", callback_data=back)
    markup1.add(mar,mar2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите,что вам нужно,если хотите вернуться в меню просто нажмите кнопку 'Назад в меню' ",reply_markup=markup1)
    elif call.data == 'cart':
        # Что то
    elif call.data == 'back':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню",reply_markup=None)
 

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Если нужно больше примеров и показать как делать - пишите

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start","help"])
def welcome(message):
    hello = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Приветствую вас меня зовут Бот!")
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    mrk = types.KeyboardButton("Каталог")
    mrk1 = types.KeyboardButton("Корзина")
    markup.add(mrk,mrk1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите в меню, что вам интересно", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_text(message):
    if message.text == "Каталог":
        markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        mar = types.KeyboardButton("Одежда")
        mar2 = types.KeyboardButton("Назад в меню")
        markup1.add(mar,mar2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите, что вам нужно, если хотите вернуться в меню просто нажмите кнопку 'Назад в меню' ",reply_markup=markup1)
    elif message.text == "Назад в меню":
        welcome(message)
```

Должно быть так, но я уже довольно давно не пишу тг ботов.

Comment: Не работает ничего

Comment: Может потому что `welcome()` должна принимать аргумент `message`?

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы не хотите работать с `callback_data` то Вы можете просто убрать кнопки `KeyboardButton` с помощью редактирования сообщения -

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,  
text="Вы уже выбрали", reply_markup=None)      # Именно `reply_markup=None` делает это
```